# Facebook 360 Encoder Error - FFmpeg libavdevice.57.dylib (not a mach-o file)

Tags: python, virtual-reality, video-encoding, oculus, oculusquest

I have been problem-solving many errors but now that I am able to run the program, I am getting the following in the error log:

```
FB360 Encoder/temp_71d65f45-encoded.mp4
dyld[46890]: Library not loaded: /usr/local/Cellar/ffmpeg@3.4/3.4.2/lib/libavdevice.57.dylib
Referenced from: <9AC373B4-E55C-323E-91A5-0CB0FA2172DF> /usr/local/Cellar/ffmpeg@3.4/3.4.2/bin/ffmpeg
Reason: tried: '/usr/local/Cellar/ffmpeg@3.4/3.4.2/lib/libavdevice.57.dylib' (not a mach-o file), '/System/Volumes/Preboot/Cryptexes/OS/usr/local/Cellar/ffmpeg@3.4/3.4.2/lib/libavdevice.57.dylib' (no such file), '/usr/local/Cellar/ffmpeg@3.4/3.4.2/lib/libavdevice.57.dylib' (not a mach-o file), '/usr/local/lib/libavdevice.57.dylib' (no such file), '/usr/lib/libavdevice.57.dylib' (no such file, not in dyld cache)


encoding failed (expected /muxing overhead/)
```

I am on Python 3.11 (and have tried 2.7) & placed the binaries for FFMPEG in the Cellar folder manually. M1 Apple Silicon on Mac OS 13.5. I sourced my files from [Hough Hou's](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3Pygrx8BSKs&t=1007s) GDrive: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1owrUXI64Rk41i-ymwuSOd5Q9XWvh7-46

During setup, I had to run a hotfix here: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/facebookincubator/facebook-360-spatial-workstation/master/scripts/ffmpeg-workaround.sh

Which at least helped me get past the initial startup but I can't compile video.

I am looking to combine head-locked and 3rd-order ambisonics together into one video which will be uploaded to the Oculus headset and played in the default player (not on YT or anything) for the highest quality. *Any FFMPEG recipes or alternatives that do the same thing would be appreciated.*